# Double Integral involving Beta Functions (about Pareto Distribution)?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, order-statistics, numerical-integration

I have tried evaluate $(m_i,m_j)$th product moment of  $X_{(i)}$ and $X_{(j)}$ order statistics of Pareto Distribution, that is $E[X_{(i)},X_{(j)}]$, where $i\le j$ , $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ i.i.d. from Pareto Distribution and $X_{(1)}\le X_{(2)}\le .....\le X_{(n)}$. But I have encountered the following quite diffucult integral:

$$\int_1^\infty \int_1^\infty  A\ (1-x^{-v})^{i-1} \ (x^{-v}-y^{-v})^{j-i-1} \ (1-y^{-v})^{n-j}\  v^2\  x^{m_i}\ y^{m_j}\ (xy)^{-v-1} \mathrm{d}x\ \mathrm{d}y$$

where $$A=\cfrac{n!}{(i-1)! \ \ (j-i-1)! \ \ (n-j)!}$$

Then, I made some adjustments by changing the variables: $x^{-v}=t_1$, $\ y^{-v}=t_2$. Finally I get the following integral

$$A\ \int_0^1\int_0^1(1-t_1)^{i-1}\ t_1^{m_i/v}\ (t_1-t_2)^{j-i-1}\ (1-t_2)^{n-j}\ t_2^{m_/v}\ \mathrm{d}t_1\ \mathrm{d}t_2$$

I cant get out here because of  the multiplier $(t_1-t_2)^{j-i-1}$ ?. The result will be the product of the integral with two beta functions but how will do it???